# HUE Query Results - Expired

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

Team,

I am using HUE-BEEWAX (Hive UI) to execute hive queries. So far, I have been always able to access the query results of queries execute on the same day, but today I see lot of the queries results shown as expired despite running them just an hour back.

my question is?

1. When does query result set become expired?
2. What settings control this?
3. Is it possible to retain this result-set somewhere in HDFS? (how?)

Regards

Comment: I don't have a good answer for 1 and 2, though you may find it in your hive server documentation (I'm on crappy wifi, so I can't look myself right now).  You can save to hdfs with this hive query: `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/hdfs/path/' SELECT <cols> FROM <table> WHERE <statement>;`

Answer (score 2):

1. My understanding is that it's controlled by Hive, not Hue (Beeswax).  When HiveServer is restarted it cleans up the scratch directories.
2. This is controlled by this setting : hive.start.cleanup.scratchdir.

Are you restarting your HiveServers?

Looking through some code, I found that Beeswax sets the scratch directory to "/tmp/hive-beeswax-" + Hadoop Username.

Comment: I did restarted my HIVE service today morning twice.

Comment: Where do I find hive.start.cleanup.scratchdir property?

Comment: Depending on your setup.  I believe in newer versions of HUE it requires an external Hive instance.  So, the setting can be set in hive-site.xml file wherever that may be for you.  See Hive Configuration Page: (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)

Comment: +1, this is managed by Hive itself. The alternative is to download the results or save the results into HDFS or in a new table with the top right icons of the query result. For more information about the life cycle of a query: http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-and-impala-queries-life-cycle/

Comment: Thanks a brandon for all the inputs. They were really useful

Comment: one more question, when will restart HUE service - does it kill the inprocess  HIVE queries?

Comment: No, it will not.  The Hive Queries are translated into MapReduce jobs and submitted to the Jobtracker.